# How to run script when none of the while statements are reached

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have multiple while statements `while [  $scene = scene1 ]`.

When `$scene` does not equal any of the while statements, I get an error "unexpected operand".

How do I set a script so that if none of the while statements are met the script is closed, or it echos "no such scene" without an error? Such as if scene = null or scene equals none of the while statement parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If `$scene` is undefined then your line will be `while [   = scene1 ]` which is invalid command for shell.

You should quote your variable: `while [ "$scene" = scene1 ]`.